# Reorder Control Panel Navigation

Tags: control-panel, navigation

Just wondering there is current any way to control the order of navigation items in the Control Panel. Obviously not a deal-breaker, but was just interested in being ultra-crafty in my Control Panel layout for clients :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to the P&T team and the latests update to Craft (2.3.2640), this is now possible through a plugin! https://github.com/engram-design/CPNav

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe there is any way to reorder the CP navigation at this moment. The only way you would be able to achieve this is to create your own Plugin which injects some JS-magic on each page that adds your own custom HTML/CSS to replace the navigation or reorder the DOM-HTML tags.

**Edit**

I would not recommend this though..

Comment: That's what I thought, just thought to ask around - even if it gives someone an idea to come up with a solution. Don't really want to go anywhere near hacking that with JS! :D

Comment: If you go to the Craft Google+ page you can add this as a feature request :)